# Precompile Grails CoffeeScript assets for Testing with Geb

Tags: grails, testing, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, geb

I would like to create reliable functional tests for Grails application with Geb which wouldn't take ages to run so me and and other team members can run them before each commit. I'm using Grails Asset Pipeline with CoffeeScript files split into many files and grouped using index files.

The problem is following:

In development and test environment the CoffeeScript files are compiled for the first URL hit - for the first time the page is loaded. As the application grows this takes more than one minute (especially on CI server) so each of my Geb specification needs to start with `waitFor(120){...}` to ensure the specification will wait until the CoffeeScript get compiled.

I could run the functional tests with `-war` flag but than all the CoffeeScript files present get compiled multiple times (once for every reference from the CoffeeScript file, i.e. one big bundle or the application coffee, once for index file once for the file itself). Currently the compile process fires for nearly three hundreds of files instead of two. If I try to exclude some files using the `grails.assets.excludes` than the files are missing from the application bundle completely.

Are there any suggestion how can compile just the files which are needed but not excluding them from bundling into other files?

The structure can be seen in our [test app](https://github.com/MetadataRegistry/ModelCataloguePlugin/tree/develop/ModelCatalogueCorePluginTestApp/grails-app/assets) and [core plugin](https://github.com/MetadataRegistry/ModelCataloguePlugin/tree/develop/ModelCatalogueCorePlugin/grails-app/assets).